# jQuery color change on custom font working correctly in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I'm changing the color of a custom font with a jQuery-script on hover:

```
$(this).css({
   color: "#" + color
});
```

My custom font got a pretty big "R" so the color is not filling the whole letter. How can I fix this? This is just a problem with Chrome, it's working fine with FF...

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

Firefox #1
Chrome #2

Comment: seems like a bug to me. report this.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle so others can see what's happening and why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ca3rT/

The top round of the "R" is cut off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is WebKit issue, because I can reproduce it on iPad.
You should report a bug. To fix this issue you can play with style rules for element. I fixed it by adding bigger `line-height` property.

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ca3rT/3/